# How to use value of click function of addEventListener in another function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic3, angular2-directives

I want to use value of a click function in another function using angular 2. My code is written below :

```
 optionFn(id){
    let root = this.viewCtrl.instance.navCtrl._app._appRoot;
    // console.log(root);
    document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        let btn = document.querySelector('.remove-ok .alert-button-default:nth-child(2)');
        let target = event.target;
        if (btn && target.className == 'alert-radio-label') {
            let view = root._overlayPortal._views[0];
            let inputs = view.instance.d.inputs;
            console.log("inputs" + JSON.stringify(inputs));
            for(let input of inputs) {
                let input = inputs_1[_i];
                if (input.checked) {
                    // this.optionEvent1 =input.value;
                    view.instance.d.buttons[1].handler([input.value]);
                    let input1 = this.input.value;
                    view.dismiss();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    let name= this.input1.name;
}
```

So, I want to use that value of input1 in my other function.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: make `input1` as global variable or store that value in local storage

Comment: @Znaneswar I want to access value of input1 inside optionFn() method.

Comment: When a click event fires on the document only you get the input value. Therefore you should call another function with the updated input value inside input.checked condition..

Answer (score 0):

You may try for this:

```
optionFn(id){
    let root = this.viewCtrl.instance.navCtrl._app._appRoot;
    // console.log(root);
let globalMessage='';
    document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        let btn = document.querySelector('.remove-ok .alert-button-default:nth-child(2)');
        let target = event.target;
        if (btn && target.className == 'alert-radio-label') {
            let view = root._overlayPortal._views[0];
            let inputs = view.instance.d.inputs;
            console.log("inputs" + JSON.stringify(inputs));
            for(let input of inputs) {
                let input = inputs_1[_i];
                if (input.checked) {
                    // this.optionEvent1 =input.value;
                    view.instance.d.buttons[1].handler([input.value]);
                    globalMessage = this.input.value;
                    view.dismiss();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    let name= globalMessage.name;
}
```

Comment: I tried with this but stil I'm getting error as Property 'input1' does not exist in type ''